# Extracting img src using HTML agility pack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am scraping a website (https://www.greenlee.com/us/en/elec-bender-classic-w-single-emt-shoes-555esc) using HTMLAgility Pack. I want to get the image src. However, I'm getting an empty result(?).

Here's my code:

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
var htmldoc = web.Load(theurl);
var htmlnode = htmldoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[contains(@class,'thumb-sizer')");

 foreach (var item in htmlnode)
 {
    Console.WriteLine(item.InnerHtml);
 }
```

Now, the result is this (also when viewing pagesource)

```
<img ng-src="{{image.thumbnailUrl}}" alt="{{image.title}}" title="{{image.title}}">
```

But, in the developer tools, I'm seeing this

```
<div class="thumb-sizer">
    <img ng-src="https://cdn.greenlee.com/resources/images/c039f03f-cb77- 
    4c28-9a78-af339c773365" alt="ELECTRIC BENDER CLASSIC W/SINGLE EMT 
    SHOES" title="ELECTRIC BENDER CLASSIC W/SINGLE EMT SHOES" 
    src="https://cdn.greenlee.com/resources/images/c039f03f-cb77-4c28- 
    9a78-af339c773365">
</div>
```

I did a little bit of research, unfortunately, I haven't found a workaround on this one. I want to extract the **img src** link or value but from the result of the **InnerHtml**, there is no src value.

Comment: The `src` attribute is only added by client-side JavaScript, so you can't get to it without first running the scripts in a browser (or browser-like environment) and grabbing the DOM afterwards.

Comment: Thanks Joey for the response. Im guessing I have to use Selenium on this one? Not sure though, unless there's a way to run the script using HTML agility pack. I'll research further... Thanks!